# Updating TKinter (Python) label with StringVar() - Variable not defined error (possible scope issue?)

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Okay so I am trying to, every time the user updates a value in an entry box, calculate a new value from the input and display it with a label.

I'm having a few issues however, not matter how I do it, by binding a StringVar() variable to the label and updating that via the .set() method. Or by using .config(text="") method of the label itself. It throws me an error saying that either my stringVar() variable hasn't been defined or that the label isn't defined.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
def calculateFreqResolution ():
  #calculate stuff from user input
  N=numSamplesTxt.get() # number of samples
  Fs=freqTxt.get() #sampling frequency

  N=int(N) #cast them as ints
  Fs=int(Fs)
  res=Fs/N

  ###After done calculating display it
  freqRes.set(res) #DOESN'T LIKE THIS LINE


def callbackNumSamples (numSamples):
  ##code here validates input into entry box, if valid then calculates then calls calculateFreqResolution()
  calculateFreqResolution()


def callbackFreq (frequency):
  ##code here validates input into entry box, if valid then calculates then calls calculateFreqResolution()
  calculateFreqResolution()

root=Tk()

freqRes=StringVar()
freqRes.set(1)

freqResCalcLabel=Label(root, textvariable=freqRes)
freqResCalcLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=2, padx=6)


frequency=StringVar() 
frequency.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, frequency=frequency: callbackFreq(frequency))

freqTxt=Entry(root,textvariable=frequency, justify=CENTER) 
freqTxt.insert(0, 1000)

numSamples=StringVar()
numSamples.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, numSamples=numSamples: callbackNumSamples(numSamples))

numSamplesTxt=Entry(root, textvariable=numSamples, justify=CENTER)
numSamplesTxt.insert(0,1000)

root.mainloop()
```

The error I get is 'freqRes' has not been defined, despite me defining it as I have done here.

In this simplified version of the code it also gives me an error saying that 'numSamplesTxt' isn't defined when trying to use the .get() method. I have no idea why it works with my main code and not this code, but I'm assuming it's a similar issue that it has something to do with the scope of the objects?

Comment: Have you tried moving  your traces somewhere _after_ you've defined the variables that they are trying to use?

Comment: :O Placed the traces after the widget definitions and it worked like a charm, can't thank you enough! 

Strange that it was half working before that too though? I don't entirely immediately see why the position of the trace would matter.

Comment: The position matters because the trace fires as soon as you change the value (eg: `freqTxt.insert(0, 1000)`). The trace can't use a variable if it hasn't yet been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting up the traces before you've initialized all of your variables. Move the traces toward the bottom of your script:

```
...
frequency=StringVar() 
numSamples=StringVar()
freqTxt=Entry(...) 
numSamplesTxt=Entry(...)
...
frequency.trace("w", ...)
numSamples.trace("w", ...)

root.mainloop()
```